# How properly setup react-router-dom in Home Route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have this **index.js**:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={history}>
    <App/>
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

this **App.js**:

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route
      path="/login"
      render={() => <Login userError={this.state.userError} />}
    />
  <Route path="/registration" component={Registration} />;
</Switch>
```

and **Home.js**:

```
<div className="Home">
  <Header/>
  <div className="content">
    <Sidenav/>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/friends" component={Friends}/>
      </Switch>
    <Feed/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want **Friends** component to be rendered inside `content` block, but now if I try to reach `/friends` route via `Link` I am getting blank page. If I set `/friends` Route in **App.js**, it will be OK, but I won't have it in my `content` class, because it will be another page.

May you give me a hand with that?

Also in feature I will be have more items to display in `content`, that's why I put `Switch` in `Home.js`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Move your `content` class and `<Friends>`

The issue you're having is that the component `Home` is not rendering when you visit `/friends` because it will only render when you go to `/`

To fix this just move the `Route` into the *App.js* file, along with the `content` class into the `Friends` component.

To make this easier, you could make your **`content` class into a component**. This way you could wrap it around all of the stuff you render.

---

### Or move `<Friends>` and wrap `content`

What I mean by this is that you could also create your own *`Route`* component that wraps whatever component passed to it in a `Content` component. It might look similar to this:

```
const ContentRoute = ({ component, ...props }) => (
  <Route {...props} component={() => (
    <Content>
      <component />
    </Content>
  )}>
  </Route>
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I decided to merge **Home.js** and **App.js**

Answer (score 3):

**You can access demo** [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/k5nlpjovlv)

Here what I have done. This demonstrates how to set layout when page's changing.

```
- src/
-- components/
--- Header.js
--- Sidenav.js
-- pages/
--- Home.js
--- Login.js
--- withBase.js
-- App.js
-- BaseLayout.js
-- routes.js
```

At first, let's make dummy components.

**components/Header**

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => (
  <div>
    This is Header.
  </div>
);
```

**components/Sidenav**

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => (
  <div>
    This is Sidenav.
  </div>
);
```

Then, pages.

**pages/Home**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import withBase from './withBase';

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <p>Welcome Home!!!</p>
    <NavLink to="/login">Go to login page</NavLink>
  </div>
);

export default withBase(Home);
```

**pages/Login**

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import withBase from './withBase';

const Login = () => (
  <div>
    <p>You have to login here...</p>
    <NavLink to="/">Go home</NavLink>
  </div>
);

export default withBase(Login);
```

**pages/withBase**

```
import React from 'react';

export default WrappedComponent => (
  class extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      this.props.showHeaderSidenav();
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent />;
    }
  }
);
```

As you see, `withBase` is a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html). It runs `showHeaderSidenav` when the page is mounted.

**App**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import BaseLayout from './BaseLayout';
import routes from './routes';

export default class extends React.Component {
    state = {
      withHeaderSidenav: true
    }

    showHeaderSidenav = (withHeaderSidenav = true) => {
      this.setState({ withHeaderSidenav });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <BaseLayout withHeaderSidenav={this.state.withHeaderSidenav}>
          <Switch>
            {routes.map(route => (
              <Route
                exact
                key={route.path}
                path={route.path}
                render={() => (
                  <route.component
                    showHeaderSidenav={() => this.showHeaderSidenav(route.withHeaderSidenav)}
                  />
                )}
              />
            ))}
          </Switch>
        </BaseLayout>
      );
    }
}
```

**BaseLayout**

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Sidenav from './components/Sidenav';

export default ({ withHeaderSidenav, children }) => (
  <div>
    {withHeaderSidenav && <Header />}
    <div className="content">
      {withHeaderSidenav && <Sidenav />}
      {children}
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

We can say that `BaseLayout` is like a wrapper. It contains dynamic components which will be shown based on `withHeaderSidenav` prop.

Finally...

**routes**

```
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Login from './pages/Login';

export default [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: Home,
    withHeaderSidenav: true
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    component: Login,
    withHeaderSidenav: false
  },
];
```

Comment: Gosh, I will need a while to figure this out :) Thanks for the detailed answer, I will get back as soon as understand this approach :)

Answer (score 0):

You could have moved(declared) content component inside Friends component. I do not see the reason why content component should live outside of Friends component. You can declare content component inside any component that needs it.Content component does not have to mess with routing implementation